# backbone form : how to render form using a custom template

Tags: forms, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-forms

Since a backbone form extends a backbone view, I guess that using a custom template sould be done the same way.

First : Insert a template as a *script type="text/html"* element in the header

```
<head>
    [ ... ]
    <script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
        <h1>This is a template for my view</h1>
    </script>
</head>
```

Then set the view's *template* attribute using the id of the template

```
var myView= new Backbone.View.extend({
    template: '#myTemplate',
    [...]
});
```

For backbone form, the template doesn't work :

```
<head>
    [...]
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/backbone-forms.js"></script>
    <script type="text/html" id="myTemplate">
        <h2>This is my custom form template!</h2>
        <form><%= fieldsets %></form>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myform"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
                schema: {
                    id : {type : "Number", validators : ["required"]},
                    first_name: {type : "Text", validators : ["required"]},
                    last_name: {type : "Text", validators : ["required"]},
                    screen_name: {type : "Text"}
                }
            });
            var myModel = new MyModel();
            var myForm = new Backbone.Form({
                template: '#myTemplate',
                model : myModel
            });
            $('#myform').html(myForm.render().el);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code outputs the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'template' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Then I try using Underscore when setting the template attribute. It does not work either

```
var myForm = new Backbone.Form({
    template: _.template($('#myTemplate')),
    model : myModel
});
```

Also a get a different error with the above code :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'
```

I'm new to backbone / backbone form. Someone could tell me what I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
template: function(attrs) { return _.template($('#myTemplate').html(), attrs)},
```

Use template like this:

```
$('body').append(this.template({fieldsets: 'fieldsets'}));
```

See a working example http://jsbin.com/uzutes/2/